# QF_AUFBV instance has one incredibly difficult assumption

Tags: z3, z3py

The smt2 code dumped from Z3py is [here](http://www.paste.org/78265). If you scroll down to the bottom, you'll see that there is a single assumption, which, if commented out, makes the problem immediately sat.

I have several questions:

- Did I select the right theory, QF_AUFBV?
- Why does the assumption make the instance so much harder?
- Any clues how to go about debugging it?

I have solved similar instances to this and they are quite fast.

When I solve this from Z3py with verbose=10, I see output like this while it is solving:

```
(smt.restarting :propagations 35577 :decisions 13935 :conflicts 277 :restart 110 :restart-outer 110 :agility 0.0356467)
(smt.restarting :propagations 40109 :decisions 15040 :conflicts 388 :restart 100 :restart-outer 121 :agility 0.0452989)
(smt.restarting :propagations 43945 :decisions 15901 :conflicts 489 :restart 110 :restart-outer 121 :agility 0.0671191)
```

Not sure if that's helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Small changes in the input often have a huge impact on Z3s runtime, especially if they are disjunctive (like your assumption). It seems that on this problem, the SMT core solver simply gets stuck searching for a solution and after trying thousands of branches (`:decisions 13935`) it decides to give up and start from scratch (`smt.restarting...`).

The theory selection is fine. If you don't need UFs you could set it to QF_ABV, but by default Z3 will use the same tactics/parameters for those.

I'm not sure I see where there is a bug to "debug", but I suppose by "debug" you mean "make it go faster"?

Comment: I know that solve times vary (sometimes wildly) from solver to solver, but Boolector is able to solve this example instantly. I guess I wondered if there were some relevant tactics I could try, or an alternate encoding, or some solver parameters I could set that I didn't know about. Thanks for taking a look.